# calling execu in a bash while loop, not working

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

I have a bash script that has to run the same file (c execut) but with different argument of input and save the output files of the c simulation in different folders. I wrote this but I don't know why it is not working!

```
mu=1
num=0
while test $num -le 6;do
    mkdir $num
    cd $num
    while test $mu -le 100; do
            ./infosimul "$num" "$mu" 
            mu=$((mu+3))
        done
    mu=0
    cd ../
    num=$((num+1))
done
```

and the oputput is:

```
testBash.sh: 7: testBash.sh: ./infosimul: not found
```

but if I run just

```
./infosimul: 1 3
```

works properly.

I am an UBUNTU user!

Comment: You change the dir by doing `cd $num` So `infosimul` is not there in the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is changing directory by calling `cd $num` and the `infosimul` program doesn't exist in the new directory.

Try calling `../infosimul` instead or specify the full path to `infosimul`.